# Круговой массив

Tags: java, массивы

Надо написать программу, которая выводит путь, по которому, двигаясь интервалом длины m по заданному массиву, концом будет являться первый элемент. Началом одного интервала является конец предыдущего, а путь - массив из начальных элементов полученных интервалов. Круговой массив: 12345. При длине обхода 4 получаем интервалы: 1234, 4512, 2345, 5123, 3451. Полученный путь: 14253.

```
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] circle = new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите количество интервалов");
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите длину интервалов");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i : circle) {
            System.out.println(circle[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам поможет оператор %

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, подробнее

Comment: Вы знаете, что это за оператор?

Comment: оператор деления ведь?

Comment: Нет, остаток от деления. Добавил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Используйте оператор остатка от деления `%`

На каждом шаге считаете новый индекс как

```
index = (index + step) % len;
```

где len - длина массива.

Заметьте, что все элементы удастся обойти только в том случае, если len и step - взаимно простые числа (их НОД==1)

Comment: Можете показать это в коде? Буду очень благодарен)

Comment: Я уже показал. Установите index в 0 и повторяйте, пока он снова не станет нулём

Comment: Всё равно не понял

Comment: Последовательность индексов:   index = **0**;  (0+3)%5 = **3** ; (3+3)%5 = **1**; (1+3)%5 = **4** ; (4+3)%5 = **2** ; (2+3)%5 = **0** ;